# How to remember text input in PHP Forms?

Tags: php, mysql, textinput

i an new to php . please help me how to remember text input in PHP forms after go back to form ?

i have an rgister page and want to save text input in database , but if a text input existing in database go back to register page but remember text input .
please help me !

Comment: You can't "remember" it. When you are outputting the form make a SELECT query to retrieve values and put them as default (`<input name=... value=...>`)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. This is not how stackoverflow works. You need to provide something that you've tried and failed so we can help you (nobody is going to solve your problems, i.e. do your job). Also keep in mind that you shouldn't post your whole code. Identify problematic part, omit irrelevant parts, etc. to get better and faster answers. Actually, there's much more to say so read [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for better understanding how SO works.

Comment: please more explain for me how to do ?

Comment: do not redirect back to register page. just show the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP session

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['name'] = "YourSession"; 
// ...
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the data in your session.

Call

```
session_start();
```

in the form.php and your target.php. In target.php parse all your $_POST/$_GET Parameters and store them in the session.

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = check_for_valid_name($_POST['user_name']);
```

in form.php just set input default to your session Variable:

```
<input name='user_name' value='<?= $_SESSION['user_name'] ?>' />
```

edit: In form.php you can also use:

```
value='<?php isset($_SESSION['user_name'])?(echo $_SESSION['user_name']):(echo "") ?>'
```

to get rid of warnings/notices of uknown index/variable.

Comment: it should be session_start() instead of start_session()

Answer (score 0):

You can store the details in a session variable. You'll have to learn working with sessions though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="inmputname" value="<?php echo $_POST['inmputname']?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: This will generate tons of warnings upon first rendering the page, which is slow and ugly

Comment: i do this but i have an notice , i write this notice below : Notice: Undefined index: inmputnamein C:\wamp\www\Final\Template\Register1.php on line 124 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012148864{main}( )..\Register1.php:0 "/>

Answer (score 0):

define your input field something like this.this will retain values after submission

```
 <input id="user_firstname" type="text" name="user_firstname" value=<?= $_POST['user_firstmane'] ?> >
```

Comment: i do this but i have an notice , i write this notice below : Notice: Undefined index: inmputnamein C:\wamp\www\Final\Template\Register1.php on line 124 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012148864{main}( )..\Register1.php:0 "/>

Comment: its not an error ..please ignore it. or check here http://www.dmxzone.com/go/13811/php-getting-notice-undefined-index/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

```
<?php
$name = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['inputname'];
}
?>
```

And in your form,

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="inputname" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: just try `var_dump($_POST);` inside th `if(){}` or post your code, otherwise how we get what is the error

Comment: Register1.php :        <form action="Register2.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/>
        </form>
Register2.php:        $name = NULL;
var_dump($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
}

Comment: i want if the field username is repetitive , header to register1.php an keep the text input